# Objective C: Write a file programmatically to the Main Bundle

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, file, bundle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing into a file objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853014/writing-into-a-file-objective-c)

How do I create and write a file to the bundle? I have this:

```
//make path to file
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"usnews.txt", [sharedManager.articleNumber intValue] + 1]];
//write file
[textContent writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

but it writes it to the documents folder and is deleted when the app is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t write to the main bundle on iOS. Its contents are cryptographically signed as a part of the App Store submission process; modifying its contents would prevent the application from running.

Documents shouldn’t be deleted when the app is closed. Try passing in an `NSError` to receive error messages on your write. Also, are you sure that the file is writing to the location you think? You use this for the filename:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"usnews.txt", [sharedManager.articleNumber intValue] + 1]
```

But you don’t have a `%d` format specifier in it, so the number is never inserted into the filename.

Comment: Or without useless negations : It is possible when the device is jailbroken

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure u can. writing into Resources folder is not forbidden.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"txt"];
```

but as far as i know it is not a good behavior according to Apple Documentation