# Add MP3's to apps main bundle without updating

Tags: ios, swift, resources, mp3, bundle

I have an app written in Swift that is similar to a soundboard. Currently I just have a bunch of mp3s in the apps main bundle. Is it possible to remotely add more mp3s into the apps main bundle and then change a variable in the code to account for the new mp3s? I want it so that I can dynamically add new mp3s without going through the whole app review process. Ideally a user would be able to open the app the next day and find that 15 new mp3s have been added without having to download an update. Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

> You can’t write to the main bundle on iOS. Its contents are
>   cryptographically signed as a part of the App Store submission
>   process; modifying its contents would prevent the application from
>   running.

Reference from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045937/objective-c-write-a-file-programmatically-to-the-main-bundle) answer.

And you can get more information from this post: [File write with [NSBundle mainBundle] fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853014/file-write-with-nsbundle-mainbundle-fails).

[File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html):

- **< Application_Home>/AppName.app**

  > This is the bundle directory containing the app itself. Do not write
  >   anything to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory
  >   is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the
  >   signature and prevents your app from launching again.

---

- **< Application_Home>/Documents/**

  > Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data
  >   files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app,
  >   such as user-generated content. The contents of this directory can be
  >   made available to the user through file sharing. The contents of this
  >   directory are backed up by iTunes.

---

- **< Application_Home>/Library/**

  > This directory is the top-level directory for files that are not user
  >   data files. You typically put files in one of several standard
  >   subdirectories but you can also create custom subdirectories for files
  >   you want backed up but not exposed to the user. You should not use
  >   this directory for user data files. The contents of this directory
  >   (with the exception of the Caches subdirectory) are backed up by
  >   iTunes. For additional information about the Library directory, see
  >   “The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files.”

---

You can read [THIS](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_in_Swift_on_iOS_8) if you want to write a file into document directory.

Hope this will help.